# Why do you need to use this.property=property in objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, this

Why do you need to use this.property = property in objects?
Is it used to define the property to the "outside world" of the object?

```
function Person(property) {
this.property = property;
}
var john = new Person(true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Because the context a method runs in (i.e. the object bound to `this`) is not part of the global scope inside the method, unless you use `with` (which is not recommended, is not available in strict mode, and would only work for reads, not writes).

Comment: @yckart (For future reference, you can just type `[ask]`, and it will come out as [ask])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't, `john.property` would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is used to refer to the owner of the function executed:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

As said, you need it to define the `john.property`, because the `property` variable passed to the function will expire once the function is executed.